# Maximum Roth IRA Contribution in 2019

Tags: united-states, roth-ira

What is the maximum contribution for a Roth IRA in 2019? I believe it was $5500 in 2018 and curious if it had been increased.

Thanks

Comment: You could have googled this in much less time than it took to post the question... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2019, your total contributions to all of your traditional and Roth IRAs cannot be more than:

- $6,000 ($7,000 if you’re age 50 or older), or
- your taxable compensation for the year, if your compensation was less than this dollar limit.

https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/retirement-topics-ira-contribution-limits

Comment: Thanks for the link and information. That's good they increased it a little from last year.

Comment: You totally missed the effect of MAGI: https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/amount-of-roth-ira-contributions-that-you-can-make-for-2019

Comment: This link is in my link.